# Inscreasing space between header and first row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created a GridView and I have fixed my headers using the "absolute" tag in the CSS class for my headers.

It works fine except that now my headers are hiding my first row of data.

Is there a way to add space before the first row of data ??

Here's the code :

```
<asp:Panel ID="GridPanel" runat="server" Width="99%" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="500px"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#2F4F4F">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True"
            CssClass="Site.bold" Font-Size="X-Small" RowHeaderColumn="Project Number" OnRowCommand="OnRowCommand"
            OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" EnableTheming="true" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                ...
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle Font-Bold="true" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle Font-Bold="true" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can add `padding-top` for your row container.

[**jsFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/xQVK3/)

```
#container{
   padding-top:50px; /* this is example */
}
```

Comment: The "row container" would be the gridview itself ? or I need to create a specific tag ?

Comment: @ElCapitaine: you can put gridview in special tag and then set `padding-top` to that tag. this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have `CssClass="Site.bold"` in `<asp:GridView/>`.

Use it to select and add `padding-top` to each of `td` elements in the second row.

```
.Site\.bold > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td{
    padding-top:50px;
}
```